# get CSS back on dynamic phonegap apps (jQuery) $().append issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am having issues getting my CSS back when I append results from my database.

Here is my function:

```
function querySuccessOrders(tx, results) {
    console.log("Successful QUERY of the orders Table");
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log("orders table: " + len + " rows found.");
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        $('#acceptedOrdersContent').append('<li><a href="#CompleteOrderInfo'+results.rows.item(i).OrderID+'">'+results.rows.item(i).OrderID+'</a></li>');
    }
}
```

The issue is that I am losing the formatting so the list item no longer links to anything (it's not clickable). I have tried to add the `.page()` to the end and that is not working. Can anyone show me how to add the style sheet back to the new stuff that I append from the database?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not clickable? If you are handling the clicks with jQuery, you need to rebind the function to the event

Comment: It looks like my css is not being applied to the new list item and in my app it just shows up as a normal bullet list instead of the buttons that are normally made when you use the <li> tag in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a jQuery mobile listview you should refresh it after listview is populated.

It can be done like this:

```
$('#acceptedOrdersContent').listview('refresh');
```

Here's an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/. In this example I am using $.ajax to load some remote data and dynamically show it in a listview. After listview is populated I am calling a ***.listview('refresh');*** to restyle it again.

Comment: Uncaught cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh':13
here is my html
    <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Simple list</h2>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="acceptedOrdersContent" data-theme="a">
            </ul>
           </div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#acceptedOrdersContent').trigger('create');
```

That should force `jquery-mobile` to apply the styling. If it's still not working try to do it in the whole page.

Comment: Where would I put that? also the element already exists before I am appending to it. I tried to add that line to the end of the function after the loop and it did not work.